# condition for matrix that are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Find condition for matrix that are linearly dependent.

Comment: Posting these kind of questions is not going to get you anywhere...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the matrices to be linearly dependent, you need:

$$
\alpha\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} 1&2\\-1&0  \end{matrix}\right)+\beta\left(\begin{matrix} 2&-3\\-2&1 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} a&b\\c&d  \end{matrix}\right)
$$

This gives you the condition:

$$
\left(\begin{matrix} \alpha+2\beta&2\alpha+3\beta\\-\alpha-2\beta&\beta  \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix} a&b\\c&d \end{matrix}\right)
$$

From this, you get the conditions that $b+d=a=-c$ and then the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that you need for the linear dependence are $\alpha=a-2d$, $\beta=d$.